# For which field $F$ and prime $p$, the polynomial $x^p-x\in F[x]$ has a multiple root?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

For which field $F$ and prime $p$, the polynomial $x^p-x\in F[x]$ has a multiple root ?

If $F$ has caracteristic $p$, then $(x^p-x)'=-1$ and thus has no multiple root. So is it in any field of characteristic $q\neq p$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the derivative criterion

> given a root $r$ of the polynomial $f$, $r$ is a multiple root of $f$ iff it is a root also of its formal derivative $f'$.

Suppose the characteristic $q$ of the field is different from $p$. Then
$$
x^{p} - x = (p x^{p-1} - 1) \frac{1}{p} x + x \cdot \frac{1 - p}{p}.
$$
If $q \mid p-1$ (so that $q > 0$ and $p > 2$), then
$$
\gcd(x^{p} - x, p x^{p-1} - 1) = p x^{p-1} - 1,
$$ 
so that the roots of the derivative $p x^{p-1} - 1$ are multiple roots of $x^{p} - x$, see the examples of Dietrich Burde and Don Antonio.

If $q \nmid p - 1$, one more division will show that
$$
\gcd(x^{p} - x, p x^{p-1} - 1) = 1,
$$
so there are no multiple roots.

Answer (score 1):

What about $\;F=\Bbb F_2\;,\;\;p=3\;$ ?:

$$x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x-1)^2$$

Comment: thank you. So, is there a general answer for this question ?

Comment: @user386627 We have that $$x^7-1=x(x^3-1)(x^3+1)=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ Now, zero cannot be multiple, and $\;1\;$ is multiple iff $\;1+1+1=0\;$ or $\;1-1+1\;$ is. The second option is absurd, and the first one is possible when char$\,F=3\;$, as Dietrich's answer shows. Other possibilities is when either quadratic above has multiple root, which can occur only if $\;-3=0\;$ and we're back again in char$\,F=3\;$ .Finally, it can happen with char$\,F=2\;$ since then $\;x^3-1=x^3+1\;$, so we could have $\;x^6-1=(x^3-1)^2\;$ and we have back my answer.

Comment: @user386627, I believe I have given it in my answer.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Yes ! Thanks a lot, your answer help a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, take $p=7$. Then
$$
x^7-x=x(x + 2)^3(x + 1)^3
$$
has multiple roots over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm making a mistake, but $\;-4=3\;$ is a root of that polynomial since :$$x^6-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;3^3+1=0\pmod 7$$ ...and it doesn't appears in your decomposition, as far as I can see.

Comment: I am taking modulo $3$, not $7$. So it is the factor $x$, for $x=3=0$.

Comment: Oh, sorry: I saw $\;p=7\;$ and thought of $\;\Bbb F_7\;$. Thanks.